# graphviz arrow, node, table - I'm looking for a solution to avoid a double arrow?

Tags: graphviz, arrow-functions

I generate a code for graphviz. This network plan always contains 2 arrows for there and back directions. Unfortunately, 2 separate arrows are displayed in the example - but I don't want that...

[image: network plan]

Would anyone have an idea how to avoid the red double arrow? Are there perhaps other options that need to be considered?

```
digraph {

node [shape=box, style=filled, fillcolor=white, color=grey, margin=0];

graph [bgcolor=floralwhite];

edge[arrowhead="normal", color="darkblue", arrowsize=1];

rankdir=LR;
concentrate=true;


AAA [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" color="black">
        <TR><TD><B>10.182.2.1</B></TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>AAA</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>Switch1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="111">1/1/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="121">1/2/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="161">1/6/1</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];


BBB [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" color="black">
        <TR><TD><B>10.182.2.2</B></TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>BBB</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>Switch2</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="141">1/4/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="151">1/5/1</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];

CCC [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" color="black">
        <TR><TD><B>10.182.2.3</B></TD></TR> 
        <TR><TD>CCC</TD></TR> 
        <TR><TD>Switch3</TD></TR> 
        <TR><TD PORT="111">1/1/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="161">1/6/1</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];


DDD [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" color="black">
        <TR><TD><B>10.182.2.4</B></TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>DDD</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>Switch4</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="141">1/4/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="151">1/5/1</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];


EEE [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" color="black">
        <TR><TD><B>10.182.2.5</B></TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>EEE</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>Switch5</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="111">1/1/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="121">1/2/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="161">1/6/1</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];


BBB:141 -> CCC:161
BBB:151 -> AAA:121

AAA:111 -> EEE:161
AAA:121 -> BBB:151
AAA:161 -> DDD:141

CCC:111 -> DDD:151
CCC:161 -> BBB:141

DDD:141 -> AAA:161
DDD:151 -> CCC:111

EEE:161 -> AAA:111


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove one of the edges & add **dir=both** as an attribute of the other edge.

```
digraph {

node [shape=box, style=filled, fillcolor=white, color=grey, margin=0];

graph [bgcolor=floralwhite];

edge[arrowhead="normal", color="darkblue", arrowsize=1];

rankdir=LR;
concentrate=true;


AAA [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" color="black">
        <TR><TD><B>10.182.2.1</B></TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>AAA</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>Switch1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="111">1/1/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="121">1/2/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="161">1/6/1</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];


BBB [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" color="black">
        <TR><TD><B>10.182.2.2</B></TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>BBB</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>Switch2</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="141">1/4/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="151">1/5/1</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];

CCC [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" color="black">
        <TR><TD><B>10.182.2.3</B></TD></TR> 
        <TR><TD>CCC</TD></TR> 
        <TR><TD>Switch3</TD></TR> 
        <TR><TD PORT="111">1/1/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="161">1/6/1</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];


DDD [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" color="black">
        <TR><TD><B>10.182.2.4</B></TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>DDD</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>Switch4</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="141">1/4/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="151">1/5/1</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];


EEE [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" color="black">
        <TR><TD><B>10.182.2.5</B></TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>EEE</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>Switch5</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="111">1/1/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="121">1/2/1</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD PORT="161">1/6/1</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    >];


BBB:141 -> CCC:161
BBB:151 -> AAA:121

AAA:111 -> EEE:161
AAA:121 -> BBB:151
AAA:161 -> DDD:141  [dir=both]  // double-headed

CCC:111 -> DDD:151
CCC:161 -> BBB:141

//DDD:141 -> AAA:161  // do not draw
DDD:151 -> CCC:111

EEE:161 -> AAA:111
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but unfortunately that's not an option for me. The export delivers both directions. Another point is the control option, if there is only one arrow direction at the plot, something is wrong (bidirectional links)

Comment: I'm exporting about 300 network elements with 3-4 connections, so manual control is not possible.

If I export without the html structure (without individual ports), there are no problems with the arrows. Why are the arrows separated?

Comment: I do not know why these two edges are not combined.  There seem to bug(s) in the concentrate code.  If all edges are bi-directional, give every edge **dir=both** and only export one of the two edges.  If this is inconvenient in your export program, it can be done with **gvpr**

Comment: ok thanks, do you have an example of how to use gvpr???

Comment: Long answer provided in Graphviz Forum https://forum.graphviz.org/t/dot-problem-two-edges-are-not-combined/2101

Answer (score -1):

with „splines=false“, I can prevent the double arrows. how do I make sure the arrows don't cross the nodes?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd4HX.jpg